# Wait material dialog to fully render content before open in Angular

Tags: material-ui, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using **Material MatDialog** in my **Angular** project to display dialogs.

However sometimes when I use `MatDialog`'s `open` method to open a dialog, I can see the **dialog instantly popping up as a blank dialog and then seems like it is refreshed with it's dynamic content**.

What is a proper way to **wait for the content to be ready before opening the dialog so that we can ensure this instant refresh of content does not happen**?

Code sample is shown below:

```
constructor( private dialog: MatDialog) {
   
}

public openDialog(): void {
   const config = {
                 width: '500px',
                 height: '500px'
               }
   this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, config);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `openDialog` function inside of Observable where you are fetching the data, and you can make use of an `afterOpened` event to wait for the dialog to be ready.

Something like this:

```
fetchData() {
  this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
    // Process the retrieved data
    // ...
    
    // Open the dialog without passing the data
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(YourDialogComponent);
    
    // Subscribe to the afterOpened event to wait for the dialog to be ready
    dialogRef.afterOpened().subscribe(() => {
      // Pass the data to the dialog once it is ready
      dialogRef.componentInstance.data = data;
    });
  });
}
```